# Openlayers 3 unable to fire click event on Android mobile phone

Tags: android, google-chrome, openlayers-3, mobile-chrome

After hours of research and testing, I am experiencing a change in behavior in Openlayers 3 on Android phone devices using Chrome. The problem may be seen here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html?q=popup. Try and open the page in an Android phone in Chrome. Then try to click the map. The only way I am able to consistently receive a popup is to kind of whip my finger at the phone, touching the screen just minimally for a short period of time. Here is what I know:

- Works on Apple mobile devices, desktops, Android phone Firefox, and Android tablet Chrome
- Doesn't work on Android Chrome on a phone
- Click and double click events do not work
- moveend event does fire
- Working fine last week

The evidence points to a Chrome issue on Android phones but I am unsure. Has anyone else experienced this problem? How did you resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a known issue please see discussion here for details: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/6778

Comment: Thanks! I was able to implement a solution based on this.